# Womp womp sound coming from rear

Tags: toyota, brakes, tires, camry

On my 2011 Toyota Camry, there was a womp womp sound coming from the rear, associated with some shaking of the car. It does it when you take off, slow down or cruise on the highway. First I put two new tires on at the back, since I thought I had a bad tire problem. It made it better for a little while, but then it came back.

It was time to change the brakes anyways, so I did because I suspected warped rotors. So I changed rotors and brakes today, it seemed like it did help a little bit not quite all the way.

What could this be?

Do you think the tires are messed up because of warped rotors?

Answer (score 4):

Probably bad struts or shocks. The fact you changed the brakes and tires will eliminate that as a cause. If your shocks were completely empty and you would be be riding on your springs with no dampening effect. That would definitely cause such a sound

Answer (score 2):

Warped rotors won't mess tires up. Check the following:

- your wheels are properly balanced
- your tires are inflated to the proper pressure
- your 4-wheel alignment is good
- your bumper cover is properly attached
- your exhaust system is properly attached
- nothing got stuck under the car (plastic bags)
- inspect at your wheel cylinders, hubs and bearings at the back, they may be worn or damaged